# Record and send audio to an API in Xcode with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, audio

I want to use the [Wit API](https://wit.ai/docs/api) to recognize speech. In Xcode, how can I record audio, send it to the API, and read the response?

I was trying to use [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureSession), but how can I only start recording when input or speech starts, and how can I send this to Wit quickly?

Also, is this even a reasonable task? Could Wit return a result in < 2 seconds?

Comment: Any tried codes ? p.s. leave Xcode tag alone; it's only an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set up all if your commands on wit.ai more information on how to do so can be found here https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart

From there you need to create the wit button and then record the response which will all be done through wit. Here is sample code https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-ios-helloworld